# Can we transfer files from one android app to another

Tags: android, nfc

I need to develop an app to transfer files from one android (NFC enabled devices) device to other using NFC. My app creates small data files which i want to transfer from one device to other. Rather than connecting phones to PC and transferring files; is there a way of using NFC and doing it on a tap.

While reading about [NFC](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/index.html),  it says

> NFC allows you to share small payloads of data between an NFC tag and an Android-powered device, or between two Android-powered devices.

Does that mean we can only share small data but not the files between two devices. I know that we can share url, photos, videos, contact etc.
Is there a way to transfer files between two Android devices????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NFC payloads are usually very small, and you will rarely be able to fit an entire file inside them.

File transfer apps that utilize NFC, including the inbuilt Android Beam, use NFC to establish a Bluetooth connection between the two devices, and then use Bluetooth to transfer the files. This is generally faster and more reliable than attempting to transfer the file piece by piece over NFC, which would also require multiple taps.

Comment: Thanks Raghav. Is there any link/doc/article explaining these steps in detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via [`setBeamPushUris`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#setBeamPushUris%28android.net.Uri%5B%5D,%20android.app.Activity%29). The system will automatically switch to another transport medium for transferring the files

Check out [this](http://r3---bru02t11.c.bigcache.googleapis.com/io2012/presentations/live%20to%20website/125.pdf?st=ts&ir=1) presentation at IO 2012 for an explanation and example